# A user cannot access a dashboard on zabbix server after zabbix upgrade to 6.4

Tags: zabbix

I recently upgraded a Zabbix server from version 5.x to 6.4,
after doing so, a regular user (not an admin) stopped being able to access a certain dashboard on any of the hosts he have access to.

**Reproduction scenario:**

1. log in to zabbix frontend
2. search for the host name using the search bar -> will give you the search results page
3. in the search result page, on the relevant host line, click on "Dashboards" in the "Monitoring" section
4. result -> an empty Dashboards page saying "No data found"
5. doing the same steps 2-4 with a privileged user (admin) gives the correct dashboard

**What I already tried:**

- In the "Users" page -> "Permissions" tab: I verified that the user has read access to the host group in which this host belongs to
- In the "Users" page -> "Permissions" tab: I verified that the user has "Dashboards" permission
- Using the same 1-2 steps I checked that the user have access to any of the graphs that are used in the relevant dashboard.
- I tried to add another dashboard with one graph to the same host template, couldn't see any of them from the regular user.

Any further ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed same issue after upgrading to 6.4.10
(Oracle Linux 9, LAMP)

It is neccessary to enable modules for the role in section "Access to modules".
[image]